# summation of vector containing long long int using accumulation

Tags: c++, accumulate

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N;
    cin>>N;
    long long int x,sum=0;
    std::vector<long long int> v;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        cin>>x;
        v.push_back(x);
    }
    /*vector<long long int>::iterator itr;
    itr = v.begin();
    for(itr=v.begin();itr<v.end();itr++)
        sum += *itr;*/
    sum = accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),0);
    cout<<sum;
    return 0;
}
```

My program is returning abstract value using accumulate, but if I use the for loop, the answer is coming.

Comment: @tobi303 : That sounds like an answer.  (In fact, it *is* the answer.  The OP has instantiated `std::accumulate<std::vector<long long int>::iterator, int>`)

Comment: `std::accumulate` has a separate template parameter for the initial value. No restriction that it has to be the same type as the elements. The only possibly likely problem with using `int` there is overflow, really.

Comment: @chris: Well yes.  But if you have a vector of long long int, it is highly likely that values >2G are at least possible - and hence that overflow *will* be the problem.

Answer (score 37):

`std::accumulate` has a small pitfall that is the initial value that you pass. One can easily overlook that this value is used to deduce the parameter `T` that is also the return type (and the return type is **not** necesarily the `value_type` of the container). Fix it by passing a `long long` as initial value:

```
    sum = accumulate(v.begin(),v.end(),0LL);
```

Comment: @Ron: or even `0LL`.

Comment: If only they had made `T` the first template argument, so that it could be specified explicitly instead.

Comment: @Jarod42 Agree.

Comment: This can be useful if accumulating a vector of long - you may want the accumulator to be of type long long in order to guard against overflow.