# how can you make a function that accepts both float and double in c++

Tags: c++

I dont know if its even possible but i want to make this function that calculates mean of vector accept both float and double. is there any way to make it? thanks.

````cpp
#include <numeric>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <vector>

int mean(std::vector<float> var)
{
    int number = var.size();
    int varAcc = std::accumulate(var.begin(), var.end(), 0);
    return varAcc / number;
}```
````

Comment: in some sense the answer is already in your code. Look at `std::accumulate`, it is a template and it takes iterators as parameters, thats what enables it to accumulate elements of any type

Comment: You probably want to replace `int` by `float`/`double` and 0 by `0.`/`0.f`/`T{}`.

Comment: if you want a function for 2 different types, then there are many more or less complicated solutions, the simple one is always to provide two overloads

Comment: `how can you make a function that accepts both float and double in c++` Like this: `void foo(float, double);`

Comment: Is your problem, that you already don't get the expected result for your actual function, because `varAcc` and the return value is `int` and the result I truncated due to that. Or is that truncation on purpose, and you want to extend that function to also accept a `std::vector<double>` besides the `std::vector<float>`?

Comment: @t.niese actually truncation already happens in `accumulate` due to the `0` initial value

Answer (score 1):

You can use templates to make it work with all the types.

```
template<typename T>
T mean(const std::vector<T>& var)
{
    int number = var.size();
    T varAcc = std::accumulate(var.begin(), var.end(), T{});
    return varAcc / number;
}
```

This is how you write less code and make things work on the types that supports the operations used in the function templates and template classes.

Comment: please consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46691683/4117728. your code yields wrong results for `double` or `float`

Comment: replace `0` with `T{}`

Comment: If you change pass by value to pass by reference you then should consider using `const`, not only because `var` is not changed in the `mean` function but also because your `mean` function now does not accept temporaries.

Comment: i got it, I am changing.